# Magnific-Popup: error on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magnific-popup

I use Magnific-Popup to show images dynamicaly. Magnific-Popup opens the images but when I close the image I get in concole the following error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)mfp(\.|$)/: Stack overflow
```

My js code is:

```
$('#display-modal div.modal-body').delegate(' table.damage_titles .photo_1 img', 'click', function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#display-modal').modal('hide');
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items:{
            src: image,
         },
        type: 'image'
    });
});
```

When I use a path to the image and not dynamicaly it works fine.

I open the images from a modal, so I use `modal('hide')` to remove the modal before showing the image.

Below I paste my code:

I open the modal and call function to add content:

```
$('.damage_details').on('click', function(){
    $('#display-modal').modal('show');
    view_damage_popup($(this));
});
```

The function

```
function view_damage_popup(button) {
    var damage = button.attr('id');
    $.post(params.url + 'ajax/get_damage_details', {'damage_id': damage}, function(result)
    {
        var details = $.parseJSON(result);
        console.log(details.room);

        $('#display-modal h3').html("Damage Details");

        $('#display-modal div.modal-body').html('')
            .append( 
                    '<table class="damage_titles table table-bordered tablesorter table-striped"><thead><tr>' +
                    '<th width="33%">Photo 1</th>' +
                    '<th width="33%">Photo 2</th>' +
                    '<th width="33%">Photo 3</th>' +
                    '</tr></thead><tbody><tr>' +

                    '<td class="photo_1">'+(details.photo_1?'<img class="example-image" src="'+params.url+'assets/uploads/damages/'+details.photo_1+'" alt="image-1"/>':'No Image')+'</td>' +
                    '<td class="photo_2">'+(details.photo_2?'<img class="example-image" src="'+params.url+'assets/uploads/damages/'+details.photo_2+'" alt="image-1"/>':'No Image')+'</td>' +
                    '<td class="photo_3">'+(details.photo_3?'<img class="example-image" src="'+params.url+'assets/uploads/damages/'+details.photo_3+'" alt="image-1"/>':'No Image')+'</td></tr></tbody></table>' +

        $('#display-modal div.modal-body div.form-group').append('<div class="messages"></div><br/><br/>');
    });
}
```

And finaly Magnific-Popup code:

```
$('#display-modal div.modal-body').delegate(' table.damage_titles .photo_1 img', 'click', function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#display-modal').modal('hide');
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items:{
            src: image,
         },
        type: 'image' // this is a default type
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a **working** snippet for this, including the `close` call. That's will be easier for us to debug it with you..

Comment: I edit the question adding my code!

Comment: For the Close Call i didin't write anything more than Magnific-Popup's code.